# Langchain not returning full response expected from OpenAI model

Tags: streamlit, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am developing an app using **streamlit** and **langchain** to recommed albums to get into artists I don't know well yet.

The problem is, langchain is not returning the full response from the OpenAI model, leaving the recommendation incomplete if the output expected is a longer text.

Here is my LLMChain code:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from os import getenv
from langchain import OpenAI, PromptTemplate, LLMChain

load_dotenv()
OPENAI_API_KEY = getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

llm: OpenAI = OpenAI(
    temperature=0.7,
    openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
)

prompt_template: PromptTemplate = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=['artists'],
    template="""Recommend me a good album to get into the following artists and give me a brief overview
    of the respective releases suggested: {artists}"""
)

album_recommender_chain: LLMChain = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt_template
)
```

And here is my streamlit code:

```py
import streamlit as st
from open_ai.llm_album_recommender import album_recommender_chain
from openai.error import RateLimitError

st.title('Album Recommender')

user_input: str = st.text_input('Insert one or more artists/band (separated by commas)')

if st.button('Send!') and user_input:
    try:
        response: str = album_recommender_chain.run(
            artists=user_input,
        )
        print(response)
        st.write(response)

    except RateLimitError as e:
        print(e)
        st.markdown(
            e.code,
            """:red[Error:] You exceeded the OpenAI calls limit.
            """
        )
```

When I put these example inputs, the answer from the model is incomplete, not giving the full recommendation for Jay-Z (the last one of the input):

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPMVg.png)

I also put  `print(response)` in the code to check if the problem is with streamlit limit of characters, but the response (from the LLM) printed on the terminal is the same as the output on the streamlit.

Hope someone can help me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try to adding `max_tokens=-1` into the

```
llm = OpenAI(
    temperature=0.7,
    openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY
)
```

so it looks like this:

```
llm = OpenAI(
    temperature=0.7,
    openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
    max_tokens=-1
)
```

this solved the problem for me at least, but there could be a better solution here in the params maybe: https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/llms/langchain.llms.openai.OpenAI.html